# Attempting to render or redirect_to specified url if optional parameter is not passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, render, optional-parameters, pushstate

I have a route with an optional parameter

```
name GET    /:name(/:age)(.:format)         users#name
```

In the associated controller I want to say that if the optional age parameter isn't passed (as in a url like localhost:3000/FirstName%20Lastname/) then bring them to a route with an age such as localhost:3000/FirstName%20Lastname/25.

My attempt in the controller is here:

```
def name
 @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
 !params[:age].nil? ? gon.currentyr = params[:age] : render name_path(@user.age)
 ...
end
```

But this results in a random error "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
I don't think the problem is actually syntax because when I change it to

```
!params[:age].nil? ? gon.currentyr = params[:age] : gon.currentyr = @user.age
```

It works without putting adding the age parameter to the end of the URL.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to redirect user to the page with age parameter of 25 unless provided?

Comment: Exactly. It's not 25 all the time.  I get that value through @user.age

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def name
  redirect_to users(params[:name], 25) if params[:age].blank?
  # (rest of your action)
end
```